# Shouldn't software installer problems be in-scope on SU even if the software happens to be a game?

Tags: discussion, gaming, scope

I was surprised [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/125931/how-do-i-install-myst-4-revelation-on-os-x-10-6) on Superuser got closed as "out of scope". Basically the question was, "Why is this software installer crashing on my new OS, when it never crashed on my old OS?". But apparently because the content of what the problematic installer was installing happened to be a game, the question was closed as out-of-scope.

There was really nothing gaming-specific about this question. It wasn't like "What hardware should I use for gaming?".

Answer (score 2):

If it was just a software installer problem, then it would still be open.

It was also flagged to close with a question on if it was allowed to stay open because it was a PC game. No, that's not a free pass.

The question is purely about the one game and [games are out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6542/are-video-game-questions-appropriate-for-superuser).

Comment: How is a question about an installer "purely" about the game it installs? I'm not a gamer, I have no interest in gaming, and I'm glad SU is kept free of gaming questions. But I *do* have an interest in figuring out crashing installers, and SU seems like the best place for that.

Comment: So was it a game installer for Myst the game or was it a software installer for something else entirely and not dependent on it being Myst at all? @spi

Comment: I'm going to have to disagree with you on this one. The problem is clearly an OS or software problem. Not a "gaming problem." Under example #3 in Jeff's accepted answer (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6542/are-video-game-questions-appropriate-for-superuser), **"pc/mac *peripherally* gaming related questions may be allowed."** A crashing problem at the earliest stages of installing a piece of software is certainly only ***peripherally* related** to the *type* of software they are installing.

Comment: Going to call that one an edge condition of either way then. The community can always vote to reopen. But am still calling it out as a game question. @rob

Comment: Fair enough. "Edge condition," it is. Thanks for listening.

Comment: I stand by @random, if the community thinks edges cases should be opened they can, but I personally think these questions need a different platform

Comment: @random at the time it was closed, it was unknown if that particular software package used a one-off custom installer, or if that issue might apply to a commonly used installer platform.